# Scroll Table view to future dates programatically ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

In my application, I am showing a TV Guide which contains 11 days of data. It has data from current date to 10 days and 1 day previous data in array.

Whenever I launch the guide, I should point the table to the current time and when I scroll forward I should able to see next day data and while scroll backward i should be able to see previous day data. I am using collection-view in each table view cell. I achieved horizontal scrolling by using multiple collection view in each table view cell.

Comment: Post your data array too. You can use `scrollToItem(at: IndexPath)` to keep your `collectionview` at current date at app launch.

Comment: I have collection view in each table view cell.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sharad Chauhan said for the `collectionView`, you can use `scrollToRow(at: IndexPath, at: UITableView.ScrollPosition, animated: Bool)` on your `tableView` to scroll to the first item like so:

```
tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
```

*(sorry, wrong code before)*

Be careful, `collectionView`s crash if they cannot scroll to the given IndexPath, that may be the same for `tableView`s.
A crash like that could happen if you scroll the view before it has loaded the cells with your data.